# Using definite article with "total"

Tags: british-english, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Should I use definite article before "total"?

Prior context: rehabilitation, describing patients' used physical therapy hours

**Sentence in the middle of this work:**

> In contrast, total received post-acute PT changed only in four
> counties.

> In contrast, the total received post-acute PT changed only in four
> counties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the PT concept has already been introduced; thus, the definite article would be used. Additionally, "only" is best placed directly before the word it modifies:

> In contrast, the total received post-acute PT changed **in only** four counties.